# How to stream live mjpeg?

Tags: c#, image, video-streaming, rtp, mjpeg

I am using directshow sample grabber in order to take pictures with rate of 25 fps from a web cam. Using pic resolution of 640x480. Pic size is around the 25500 bytes after converting it to jpeg. I am sending the frame using the rtp protocol. Also sending voice encoded with g711 with rtp protocol on different port. I am struggling a delay issue with the video from time to time. Maybe the jpeg size is too big? Do I need some how to compress the to mjpeg before sending?

When I recieve the frame on the client side, I am showing it in a picturebox. Changing the pictrue in the picturebox in small period of time give us the illusion of video.

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1):

https://net7mma.codeplex.com/ has an implementation of this, you would use the `RtspServer` and just put the new images in a directory and use the class `RFC2435Stream` which does this for you by monitoring that directory.